# Why was this question about why US officers sometimes stamp non-US passports closed as a duplicate of whether they do it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicates

The question [Why do US officers sometimes stamp non-US passports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168838/1810) was closed as a duplicate of the question [When entering the United States as a permanent resident and with Global Entry, does the US immigration agent stamp one's passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149678/1810).

The first question asked *why* the US officers may stamp the passport, whereas the second (and older) question asked *whether* the US officers stamp the passport. And unsurprisingly, none of the two answers for [When entering the United States as a permanent resident and with Global Entry, does the US immigration agent stamp one's passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149678/1810) addressed the question of *why* the US officers may stamp the passport.

Why was the question [Why do US officers sometimes stamp non-US passports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168838/1810) closed as a duplicate of [When entering the United States as a permanent resident and with Global Entry, does the US immigration agent stamp one's passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/149678/1810), since it appears not to be a duplicate?

---

Notes:

1. There are plenty of why-questions on this website.
2. Regarding the two questions discussed in this meta question, the answers on the whether question doesn't address the why, therefore the why-question is clearly distinct.

Answer (score 3):

The questions are so much alike that they the difference between them might belong to a language site, it is too small for the travel site.

You know US officers do sometimes stamp and other times do not stamp passports. The why is not really a travel topic, it is partly covered by the whether question and the rest will be more speculation than knowledge.

The question could have been closed for one of several reasons but as I found it with several 'duplicate' votes on it already, I went with the reason and gave it the last hit.

I think one reason you get so many 'close' votes on your questions is that you ask many closely related questions and many questions that are not really on topic but off the edge of the travel theme. When you ask many questions people see as 'off topic' they will be faster voting to close the next question, even when it might be, marginally or by a small bit, on topic. That is normal human behavior, not aimed at you as a person, but at one part of your habits which are seen too often on the SE sites.

Comment: Thanks, there are plenty of why questions on this website, and in most cases one doesn't have to speculate to answer them. The answers on the whether question doesn't address the why, therefore the why question is clearly distinct.

Comment: Why am I not allowed to comment on your post history while you are allowed to comment on mine?

Comment: I read your comment, did not see it as relevant to this case. So I deleted it as seen.

Comment: My comment was mentioned that while you claim "The why is not really a travel topic", you've answered plenty of why-question, which makes me wonder whether you made up the statement to find a pretext to claim that [Why do US officers sometimes stamp non-US passports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168838/1810) is off-topic.